# Screen resolution java code

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to know how to fix the browser resolution for a pc of settings 1280X720 so that the web application developed in java using gwt doesnt looked stretched.I have tried

```
int width= windows.getClientWidth();
int height= windows.getClientHeight();
RootPanel.get().setHeight(height   + "px");
RootPanel.get().setWidth(width + "px");
```

Comment: Do you really expect to be able to set the user's browser window size?  HTML/CSS/JavaScript were designed so that web applications would have some limits.  Messing with the browser window is one of the areas where JavaScript has a lot of inherent limits.  I would recommend spending some time with CSS documentation so your application "doesn't look stretched."

Comment: Actually this development is in java as the development environment uses gwt with no use of applets for the coding.So its tough to use pure java to set the rootpanels width and height according to the Systems resolution.So the browser looks streatched alongwith the web application.Thanks for your reply Adam.

Comment: The whole point of GWT is compiling Java code to JavaScript that can then run natively in the browser.  Consequently, at runtime you aren't really using "pure Java" - you are actually using JavaScript.  So any limit on JavaScript (in this case, resizing the browser window) is also a limit on Java code compiled using GWT.

Comment: Yes correct.The problem was the height and width of the panel was set statically in the rootpanel.ui.xml and thus any changes externally made to it were not affecting the layout of the panel.

Answer (score 1):

You sure have some main component which is added to the `RootPanel`. A `DockPanel` or `LayoutPanel` or whatever you use as top component. Just fix the size of this panel and there you go. `RootPanel.get()` gives you a handle to the body element, changing the size of a sites body element does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was looking into doing something along what you're looking into with a game I've been working on. And I found that there is a much better way to handle it. Once you get it worked out it will work with any resolution

example, I was trying to display items in an inventory. but with using integer values in the x, y  for the images they would move around depending on what resolution the user was using.

so I baselined some x, y values like so

```
g.drawImage(inventory, width - 499, height / 2 - 20, null);
int ixt = width - 499;
int iyt = height / 2 - 20;
g.drawImage(broadsword, ixt + 10, iyt + 10, null);
```

this way it starts out at the 0,0 of the inventory image, and moves over and down 10 pixels and places the item image.

so no matter what resolution you'r in, it shows up in the same place every time.

Hopefully you can work something like that into your program.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the browser size with

```
Window.resizeBy(500, 400);
```

however the window has to be opened with `window.open`.

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#resizeBy(int, int)